# android:permission in <application>

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I have noticed that Android framework [allows](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#prmsn) `android:permission` in `<application>`.
For example, consider the following manifest file.

```
<application android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET">
    ...
</application>
```

In the above example, to launch my application the launcher app (e.g., home screen) needs `INTERNET` permission. In reality, no one permission protect their application (I may be wrong here). But, I really don't understand the practical use-case of it. When will we use permissions in `<application>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#prmsn):

> This attribute is a convenient way to set a permission that applies to all of the application's components

So, if every `<activity>`, `<service>`, `<provider>`, and `<receiver>` in your manifest would have the same `android:permission` attribute, you could eliminate the redundancy and simply have the attribute in `<application>`.

In practice, I suspect that this is almost never used, except perhaps by plugin apps restricted to work only with some host app via a `signature`-level permission.

Answer (score -1):

Try to put like the following outside application tag:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And also if we need to perform any special permissions, you need to specify the respective permissions in manifest.

Comment: The OP is referring to `android:permission`, not `<uses-permission>`.