# android:permission tag in manifest file

Tags: android, permissions

I notice there is a tag named `android:permission` in android manifest file, but feel confused about it.

1. Does this tag only specify *ONE* permission that other components require in order to interact with it? I grep the Android framework and it seems so; and it seems that `permission-group` is *not* used for multiple permissions the current component/application requires other applications to grant.
2. Someone [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18418256/528929) that `android:permission` in  is rarely used. But when it does appear, should the components that also define these permission *override* this permission requirement *or* *append* it? The [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#prmsn) says:

> It can be overwritten by setting the permission attributes of individual components

However I saw [a research paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2185466) mentions that:

> each component can require extra permission for accessing it

I guess it is still a "override", right?

Answer (score -1):

i guess this answers your question. please check the following link
[Can an Android Service have multiple Permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473911/can-an-android-service-have-multiple-permissions)

Comment: No, that's not. that's about `uses-permission`, which denotes the permissions the application requires.